# How can i integrate php to html table

Tags: php, html, css

My friend made new design for my table but i couldnt integrate old table php code to the new design. How can i make it? Thanks

This is my old table;

```
<table align="center" width="1200" height="370" cellpadding="7">
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Sex</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Twitter</th>
                <th>Instagram</th>
                <th>Snapchat</th>
                <th>Details</th>
            </tr>

            <?php
            foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM uyeler ORDER BY RAND()LIMIT 20') as $row) {
                    echo "<tr><td>" .$row['id'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['fname'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['sex'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['country'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['age'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['twitter'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['instagram'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .$row['snapchat'] . "</td>";
                    echo ('<td><a href="details.php?id=' .$row['id'] . '" title="Panel">Details</a></td>');
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            ?>

            </table>
```

This is new design, (One line dark, one line black....)

```
<table class="table table-striped">

                                <!--Table Header -->
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="t_head">ID</th>
                                        <th class="t_head">NAME</th>
                                        <th class="t_head">SEX</th>
                                        <th class="t_head">COUNTRY</th>
                                        <th class="t_head">AGE</th>
                                        <th class="t_head">TWITTER</th>
                                        <th class="t_head">INSTERGRAM</th>
                                        <th class="t_head">SNAPCHAT</th>
                                        <th class="t_head">DETAILS</th>
                                    </tr>

                                <!--Row 01 -->  
                                    <tr class="t_light">
                                        <td>14</td>
                                        <td>Taha</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td>Russia</td>
                                        <td>2000</td>
                                        <td>Tahains</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td><a href="#">Details</a></td>
                                    </tr>

                                <!--Row 02 -->  
                                    <tr class="t_dark">
                                        <td>14</td>
                                        <td>Taha</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td>Russia</td>
                                        <td>2000</td>
                                        <td>Tahains</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td><a href="#">Details</a></td>
                                    </tr>

                                <!--Row 03 -->  
                                    <tr class="t_light">
                                        <td>14</td>
                                        <td>Taha</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td>Russia</td>
                                        <td>2000</td>
                                        <td>Tahains</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td><a href="#">Details</a></td>
                                    </tr>

                                <!--Row 04 -->  
                                    <tr class="t_dark">
                                        <td>14</td>
                                        <td>Taha</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td>Russia</td>
                                        <td>2000</td>
                                        <td>Tahains</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td><a href="#">Details</a></td>
                                    </tr>

                                <!--Row 05 -->  
                                    <tr class="t_light">
                                        <td>14</td>
                                        <td>Taha</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td>Russia</td>
                                        <td>2000</td>
                                        <td>Tahains</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td>Male</td>
                                        <td><a href="#">Details</a></td>
                                    </tr>

                                </table>
```

A part of css file;

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th
{
    background: #e0dfdf;
}

.table>thead>tr>th, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>td
{
    background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows

```
<table align="center" width="1200" height="370" cellpadding="7">
    <tr>
        <th class="t_head">ID</th>
        <th class="t_head">NAME</th>
        <th class="t_head">SEX</th>
        <th class="t_head">COUNTRY</th>
        <th class="t_head">AGE</th>
        <th class="t_head">TWITTER</th>
        <th class="t_head">INSTERGRAM</th>
        <th class="t_head">SNAPCHAT</th>
        <th class="t_head">DETAILS</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i=1;
    foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM uyeler ORDER BY RAND()LIMIT 20') as $row) {
        if ($i%2!=0)
            $class="t_light";
        else
            $class="t_dark";
        echo "<tr class='".$class."'><td>" .$row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['fname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['sex'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['country'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['age'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['twitter'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['instagram'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['snapchat'] . "</td>";
        echo ('<td><a href="details.php?id=' .$row['id'] . '" title="Panel">Details</a></td>');
        echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

What I have done is that, inside the for each loop I checks whether each of the iteration is wwhether odd or even and applies the class appropriately.

I think, you are using such a code to style alternate rows differently. This can be done with CSS selectors. No need for adding separate classes for rach rows.

In pure CSS you can do the following:

```
//for even
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #000000;
}
//for odd
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: i tried your answer but there is a little " error on this line. it works with this `echo "<tr class='.$class'><td>" .$row['id'] . "</td>";`  but with this all lines are white

Comment: you missed a `"`..it should be, `echo "<tr class='".$class."'><td>" .$row['id'] . "</td>";`

Comment: sorry, didnt get you...it should be `echo "<tr class='".$class."'><td>" .$row['id'] . "</td>";`

Comment: Now table is listing but all lines are white.

I directly add your css code at the end off file but not change anythnig. I add some part of my css file. could you help me

http://farkc.com/index.php

Comment: The css specified at the end was just an alternate solution

Comment: @Lal indeed your code cannot work. Since you forgot to increment `$i` :)

Comment: Dont add the style that are specified at the end.. Its just an alternate solution..

Comment: it works with removing /// lines :)

`
`tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #000000;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}`

Thank you very much

Comment: Oops sorry @b.enoit.be.. Forgot to mention that.. Updated the answer.. Thanks for pointing out..

Answer (score 0):

Those kind of jobs are usually done via the modulus operator `%` which help you get the remainder of a division.
 That, in your case, could allow you to find row that are even and row that are odd.

> $a % $b   Modulus Remainder of $a divided by $b.

source : http://php.net/en/language.operators.arithmetic

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM uyeler ORDER BY RAND()LIMIT 20') as $row) {
        echo '<tr class="'.($i%2 == 0 ? 't_light' : 't_dark').'">';
        echo "<td>" .$row['id'] . "</td>";
            // the other columns comes here
        echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: not work :( i check code with php checker. it say "PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected "   `echo "<td>" .$row['id'] . "</td>";`

Comment: it works but listing datas without design and side by side